# Use joystick in linux-native Valve games (tf2, css, ...)

Tags: team-fortress-2, linux

I have a simple joystick: A stick with two buttons. It is usually connected to my soundcard, and it works in many linux games. However, I see no options in tf2 to activate/use it (only: "gamepad").

Can I still use my joystick in TF2?

Please note: No wine related answers - I use the games native (via "Steam on Linux").

Comment: If you enable the "gamepad" option, does it work?

Comment: @badp: No, sadly not.

Comment: If you're using a linux distribution other than Ubuntu 12.04, you might be running into a problem caused by Steam embedding its sdl & udev libraries. Assuming your joystick exposes a file like `/dev/input/event123` file when connected, try launching steam like this: `SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/event123 steam`

Answer (score 1):

The research I've done shows mixed findings. Some sources say Team Fortress 2 only has partial controller support for Xbox 360 and PS3 controllers on PC. The Team Fortress 2 wiki also only has setup guides for [Xbox](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Xbox_360_controls) and [PS3](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/PlayStation_3_controls). The support pages for using a controller on Source do say that there is [no Mac support for controllers in Valve games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6292-PQMG-6828). According to another page, [there are drivers you can install to use a controller on a Mac](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1445-TKCN-0831). [Here are the support pages if you want to check them out.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_cat.php?id=71)

Unfortunately, control support is limited to begin with and seeing as there little to no native support for Mac's and only minimal support on PC, I don't believe there is support for Linux. Sorry :(